# Console permitting input to stdin while in sigsuspend

Tags: c

Long story short, I have two processes from the same executable. They are meant to communicate to each other and create a chat for the users in front of those processes. Call them p1,p2;

p1 will enter or the initial details (name, for example) faster, so it must wait until p2 does the same. This is where I put p1 into sigsuspend until it receives a signal that p2 is ready as well.

Now, my problem is that p1 that is in sigsuspend can type in the console and that goes right in the stdin, so when both p1 and p2 are connected and are ready to chat, p2 will receive that unwanted text p1 typed during sigsuspend.

This is extremely frustrating, as I have searched furiously for a solution for the past week and found nothing that helped me.

Of course, I found these:

```
int c;
while( (c = getchar()) != '\n' );
```

Above works for just one line, so no help.

Then, the scanf: `scanf("%*[^\n]\n");` doesn't really work for me.

It seems that this is a common problem, "flushing" stdin if I may call it that, but is there no solution? Maybe just blocking typing in the console somehow. I just need to get rid of previous garbage and start fresh with an empty stdin, before the users start chatting.

Please help.

Comment: Are your two program instances running simultaneously in the same terminal?  This sounds weird to me.

Comment: no, they are run from different terminals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I have found a little hacky solution to my problem. And I am going to put this here in case someone has the same problem.

After both users have connected and are ready to chat I do:

```
int c; while( (c=getchar()) != EOF );
```

and prompt them to press ctrl+D (adding EOF to stdin) if they want to start chatting. This way I get rid of all the unwanted text and when one of them presses ctrl+D it stops the loop for them and then I send a signal to the other process, thus interrupting the system call getchar().

After that, everything is clean and they can start chatting.

Hope this helps someone.